# Laravel 5 trouble using Eager Loading

Tags: laravel

So i have this problem getting the user data through the staff table using eager loading.

Controller:

```
public function staff()
{
    $salon = Salon::find(Session::get('salon'));
    $staff = Staff::where('salon', $salon->id)->with('user')->get();

    return view('dashboard.salon.staff', compact('staff'));
}
```

View:

```
@foreach ($staff as $staff)
    {{ $staff->user->photo }}
@endforeach
```

Model:

```
class Staff extends Model {

    protected $table = 'salonStaff';

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

I have tried troubleshooting using dd($staff) and the user relation appears null from the controller, and doing dd($staff->user) inside the foreach results in "1", nothing else.

Comment: Is the foreign key column named `user`? If so, change it to `user_id`

Comment: renaming it to user_id i get
    Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'user' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `salonStaff` where `user` = 1)

Answer (score 0):

If your primary key in user column is = 'user', you should specify in the User model with

```
protected $primaryKey = 'user';
```

if not, when using a relation, Eloquent expects a conventional foreign key like 'user_id'  ($tablename_id)

Just to be sure, try to specify the foreign key in the model relation:

```
return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user');
```

where the second argument is the real foreign key in the table.

Also try change your query like this

```
$staff = Staff::where('salon', $salon->id)->user()->get();
```